# Git Submodule Merge

Tags: git, merge, git-submodules

I have a git repository, and in a branch I've created a submodule. The submodule, called foo, replaces a file called foo. The foo repository contains one file called bar.

I committed my changes on the branch, and merged in to master. There were no conflicts, but I'm now left in the state where it says the following:

```
deleted:     foo
new file:    foo/bar
```

I'm confused as to what I need to do to resolve this. Running git config -l shows my submodule correctly.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this.  Can you describe the steps you used to split `foo` into a submodule?

Comment: I created a new repository called foo, deleted the file foo, and cloned the repo in its place. That worked fine on the branch on which I did it; it was only once I merged into master (which had had intervening commits) that I had problems.